# How to move custom IDesigner to separate assembly in the same solution?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I created a custom user control with design-time support like this:

**Project/Assembly "MyUserControl"**

- MyUserControl.cs
- MyUserControlDesigner.cs

Code is like this:

```
namespace MyUserControl
{
  [Designer("MyUserControl.Design.MyUserControlDesigner, MyUserControl", typeof(IDesigner))]
  public class MyUserControl : Control
  {
    // Some stuff here
  }
}

namespace MyUserControl.Design
{
  public class MyUserControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
  {
    // Some other stuff here
  }
}
```

As long as these two classes are in the same assembly, everything works fine. VS2012 shows all my designer options. But for obvious reasons (References to System.Design and others) I don't want to have the designer code in my MyUserControl assembly, but in MyUserControl.Design. So i create a second project in the same solution:

**Project/Assembly "MyUserControl"**

- MyUserControl.cs

**Project/Assembly "MyUserControl.Design"**

- MyUserControlDesigner.cs

Code is like this:

```
namespace MyUserControl
{
  [Designer("MyUserControl.Design.MyUserControlDesigner, MyUserControl.Design", typeof(IDesigner))]
  public class MyUserControl : Control
  {
    // Some stuff here
  }
}
```

When using this, the designer is not found at all. VS2012 does not show the component in-line selectable but like a component which has no designer attached.

Do I have to add my designer assembly to the GAC in order for VS2012 to find it or what is the problem here?

**Edit:** Everything works fine when adding a reference to MyUserControl.Design to WindowsFormsApplication1, but this is exactly what you don't want ...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make `MyUserControlDesigner` a public class.

Comment: I fixed the issue in my code above. For sure both of the classes have been public classes in my real code.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I came to exactly the same problem. It started to work for me only when I specified the the designer class the following way.

```
namespace MyUserControl
{
  [Designer("MyUserControl.Design.MyUserControlDesigner, MyUserControl.Design,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8bc98ae14acadc09", typeof(IDesigner))]
  public class MyUserControl : Control
  {
    // Some stuff here
  }
}
```